# How to bind nested data on livewire when using checkbox?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I am trying to use checkbox in `livewire 2.x`, its ok when using single property. But it is not working when using nested property.

blade :

```
@foreach ($questions as $key => $question)
    <div class="card card-primary">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="section-title mt-0">{{ $question->description }}</div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @foreach ($question->choices as $choice)
                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline col-12 col-md-5 col-lg-5">
                        <input
                            class="form-check-input"
                            type="checkbox"
                            id="checkbox-choice-{{ $choice->id }}"
                            value="{{ $question->id }}_{{ $choice->id }}"
                            wire:model.defer='answers.{{ $key }}.choices'
                        >
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="checkbox-choice-{{ $choice->id }}">{{ $choice->description }}</label>
                    </div>
                @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

then on component :

```
public $answers = [];

public $rules = [
    'answers' => 'required|array|min:1',
];

public function submitAnswers()
{
    /** @var array $validData */
    $validData = $this->validate();
    Log::info('' . json_encode($validData));

}
```

example result :

```
{"answers":[{"choices":"42_167"}]}
```

property `choices` only returns a string result, even though it is selected as multiple choices, how to make the property `choices` an array?